# Как вывести записи со срезам по дням

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть таблица **users** , в ней ячейка **date** тип - DATETIME.

В этой таблице я храню юзеров (*nick*), я хочу вывести в цикле всех зарегистрированных юзеров по дням. Например, чтобы получилось так:

`28.07.2018 : user1, user2, user3`

`29.07.2018 : user4, user5`

`30.07.2018 : user6, user7`

И так далее.

Цикл в котором вывожу всех юзеров:

```
$db = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `date`");
if ($db) while ($us = $db->fetch_assoc()) {
    ...
}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ссылка:

[How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Использование:

> ```
> create table `test`
> (
>   `date` date,
>   `nick` varchar(10)
> )
> ```

> ```
> insert into `test` (`date`,`nick`) values
> ('2018-07-28', 'user1'),
> ('2018-07-28', 'user2'),
> ('2018-07-28', 'user3'),
> ('2018-07-29', 'user4'),
> ('2018-07-29', 'user5'),
> ('2018-07-30', 'user6');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   `Date`, 
>   GROUP_CONCAT(`nick` SEPARATOR ' ') `nicks`
> FROM `test`
> GROUP BY 
>   `Date`
> ```
>
> ```
> Date       | nicks            
> :--------- | :----------------
> 2018-07-28 | user1 user2 user3
> 2018-07-29 | user4 user5      
> 2018-07-30 | user6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=878e786e544539390bf1fc55e3ca3923)*